# Typescript shows "any" when I have specified the type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's generate a situation. There is a simple abstract class that defines a piece in a board game like chess or checkers.

```js
export abstract class Piece<Tags, Move, Position = Vector2> {
  public constructor(public position: Position, public tags = null) {}
  public abstract getMoves(board: Board<Tags, Move, Position>): Move[]
}
```

The `Board` is also an abstract class.

```js
export abstract class Board<Tags, Move, Position = Vector2> {
  public constructor(
    public size: Position,
    public pieces: Piece<Tags, Move, Position>[]
  ) {}
}
```

When I try to extend this class, Typescript says that `board` in the `getMoves` method is `any`.

```js
class Checker extends Piece<Tags, Move> {
  getMoves(board /*← any */) {
    return []
  }
}
```

But why? Am I misunderstanding something about generics or abstract classes?

Comment: What is the definition of `Board`? Please edit to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare a method with the same signature as the abstract class to demonstrate you have fulfilled the contract of the abstract class.

```
class Checker extends Piece<Tags, Move> {
  public getMoves(board: Board<Tags, Move, Position>): Move[]{
    return []
  }
}
```

After that you will be able to create a `const piece:Piece = new Checker()` and be able to rely on the typing of calls to piece.getMoves(board).

This example shows the fundamental pattern (omitting the types you didn't provide implementations for)...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This it not related to generics.

e.g. when you craete a simple function and don't specify the argument type, it is `any`

```js
function test(arg) {
// arg is of type any
}
```

And the other issue is that typescript simply does not have contextually typing for overridden members. So you must list all arguments and types again in the child-class.
see [Consider contextually typing class member functions by their base class/interface members #1373](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript supports [methods overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). The compiler can't infer the type of the argument because you as a developer can specify several method signatures:

```js
class Checker extends Piece<Tags, Move> {

  getMoves():Move[];
  getMoves(x: number):Move[];
  getMoves(board: Board<Tags, Move, Position>):Move[];
  getMoves(board: any):Move[] {
    return [];
  }
}
```

Thus, you have to specify the method signature of your implementation explicitly.